# Cut software to cut 3D STL files for smaller printers

Tags: windows, 3d

I am searching for software to cut a large STL object to smaller objects for a smaller 3D printer. With Netfabb Basic I have only found out that an object can be cut with straight lines. What I am searching is a software to create puzzle-like parts, so the objects can be put together more stably.

So far I found PuzzleCut (the last version seems to be from 2012) for OpenSCAD. With OpenSCAD I have the problems that the software itself crashes a lot at my PC, and that the STL import seems to be far beyond optimal.

It does seem to do what I want with their demo STL, but the results were for different objects I tried mostly destroyed the parts of the object (not just the cut side, but also other details within the objects)

Is there some software to cut a larger STL file in pieces with either auto creation of bolts or puzzle-like structures?